# how to get datetime difference in two different rows in sql

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

[image: Difference between first entry and last entry for that day. Entries in that date can be 1 or more. If only one entry exists difference should be straight away 0]

I tried

```
try{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:attendance");
        String sel="SELECT DATEDIFF(d, checkin, checkin)"
                + " from checkinout where userid=1";
        stmt=con.createStatement();
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(sel);
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
        System.out.println("Connected");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

But exception occured 
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2.

Thank you

Comment: Try to write two queries first, one to get the first value only and the other to get the last. Once you have that you can combine then in your main query which will find the difference. Build your final query one step at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you missed the quotes for the first argument in DATEDIFF().

Most probably d ( denoting day) should be in quotes (something like "d", 'd' or "\d\").

Check the syntax for DATEDIFF with examples [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateDiff-Function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f).